# How to rigorously prove that $\mathbb Q(i)$ corresponds to $\langle \sigma \rangle$ in the Galois correspondence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\theta = \sqrt[8]{2}$, $\zeta = e^{i\pi/4}$ (primitive $8$th root of unity) and $K = \mathbb Q(\theta,i)$. Put:

$$\sigma: \begin{cases} \theta \mapsto \zeta \theta \\ i \mapsto i \end{cases}$$

I would like to prove that $\mathbb Q(i) = F$ corresponds to $\langle \sigma \rangle$ in the Galois correspondence, i.e. $\text{Gal}(K/F) = \langle \sigma \rangle$. Obviously $F$ is contained in the fixed field of $\langle \sigma \rangle$, so I have to show the other inclusion.

I can "see" why it holds: $\sigma^k$ changes $\theta$ and keeps $i$ fixed. But I can't just say "if an element  has $\theta$ in it, then it isn't fixed by $\sigma$". How to go about **rigorously** proving the equality?

Comment: Hint: The subgroup generated by sigma is index 2 and so is normal. The quotient is the Galois group of the fixed field over the base field.

Comment: @Ravi so if $L$ is the fixed field, then $[L:\mathbb Q] = \left| \text{Gal} (L/\mathbb Q) \right| = |G/\langle \sigma \rangle| = 2$, which forces $L = \mathbb Q(i)$?

Comment: That is the idea. Proving that $\langle\sigma\rangle$ has the right order takes a bit extra (but ain't difficult).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I computed everything (all the elements of the big Galois group), so I already have that! Thank you for your answer, I needed to see how these things are usually proved.

Comment: Yup, @Cauchy. I could read it between the lines that you had already worked hard. Items 1-3 in my answer are there only for the benefit of possible future readers who have not done that groundwork (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigorously, you said?

Justify the following claims:

1. Because $K=\Bbb{Q}(\theta,i)$ any automorphism $\tau\in Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is uniquely determined, if we know $\tau(\theta)$ and $\tau(i)$.
2. Because $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=8\cdot2=16$ we see that the Galois group has sixteen elements.
3. There are $8$ alternatives for $\tau(\theta)$ and two for $\tau(i)$. Hence all the combinations must occur exactly once. Hence the automorphism $\sigma$ that you described exists.
4. We have $\sigma(\zeta)=-\zeta$. Hint: write $\zeta$ in terms of $i$ and $\sqrt2$.
5. Show that $\sigma$ has order eight.
6. Let $H=\langle \sigma\rangle$. Show that $[Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}):H]=2$. Hence $\operatorname{Inv}(H)$ is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.
7. Show that $\Bbb{Q}(i)\subseteq \operatorname{Inv}(H)$, and conclude that we must have equality here.

Comment: In a first course on Galois theory I would insist on having items 1 thru 3 for full credit. It sounds like you may have done those already. Item 4 is a subtlety that is sometimes absent from related exercises on splitting fields of $x^n-m$, hence the special attention.